# How to get original (EXIF?) creation date/time of PHAsset?

Tags: ios, phasset, photosframework

`PHAsset` has a `creationDate` property that gives the creation date of the asset in UTC.

If I take a photo taken at 10:52 PM UTC-6, the `creationDate` property is 03:52 AM.

How am I supposed to know the 'true' time of the photo taken? No timezone information is supplied with the `creationDate` property, so I can't adjust this back to 10:52 PM - I have no idea what time zone to just when adjusting it...

I know I can get the EXIF creation date (or attempt to at least) using `PHImageManager requestImageDataForAsset` and using the data returned there to obtain an EXIF creation date which actually is 10:52 PM, but this results in very slow for performance when the photos are in iCloud (I need this creation date value for all assets in the user's library).  Additionally I cannot figure out how to get the EXIF creation date for videos.

I also know there are methods of obtaining a timezone from a `CLLocation`, which I could use to adjust the `creationDate` - but these methods are either rate limited and/or inaccurate

Is there another, easier way, to get this original creation date value?

To recap:

- A photo is taken at 10:52 PM in UTC-6
- PHAsset creation date is 03:52 AM in UTC
- I want to know how to get 10:52 PM UTC-6 date/time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `PHContentEditingInput`.
It will be probably slow for iCloud images too but it is worth trying as I don't think there are any other ways to do it :(

This approach does not require `ImageIO` import and needs less code so maybe it would be somewhat better than `PHImageManager requestImageDataForAsset`

You can use this `PHAsset` category to try it quickly:
https://github.com/zakkhoyt/PHAsset-Utility

Answer (score 0):

Can get exif details as below :

```
let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()

asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { input, _ in
    guard let url = input?.fullSizeImageURL else { return }
    guard let image = CIImage(contentsOf: url) else { return }
    guard let exif = image.properties["{Exif}"] as? [String: Any] else { return }

    print(exif["DateTimeOriginal"] ?? "")
    print(exif["SubsecTimeDigitized"] ?? "")
}
```

This prints:

> 2021:01:04 11:47:07

> 177